# Transposing Copy VBA

Tags: vba

For example, my spreadsheet is just a like a [21x4] array.
Now I want to separate and arrange (copy & paste) three [7x4] arrays vertically  from the abovementioned array to get a [7 x 12] array.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean something like "A1:D21" to be transformed in "A1:L7"?

Comment: I think, it would be good to edit your question and place two pictures (if not something editable). The existing situation followed by the desired one. An array is usually represented in rows and columns. Now, speaking about 'paste vertically' I cannot understand what you want.

Comment: So no actual transpose operation needed (swapping rows for columns)? You just want to move 7×4 blocks from being stacked on top of each other, to being next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. I hope I understood what you meant in your question...
Supposing that you followed the normal convention to expres the array in terms of rows followed by columns:

```
Sub sliceArrayTransposeHoriz()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, slice, nrRows As Long
 Dim col As Long, lastRow As Long, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 nrRows = 7: col = 4: lastRow = 21
 arr = sh.Range("A1:D" & lastRow).Value 'put the range in an array
 For i = nrRows + 1 To lastRow Step nrRows
    'take an array slice of 7 rows and 4 columns:
    slice = Application.Index(arr, Application.Evaluate("row(" & i & ":" & _
                                    i + nrRows - 1 & ")"), Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
    'drop the slice content in the next empty column:
    sh.cells(col + 1).Resize(UBound(slice), UBound(slice, 2)).Value = slice
    col = col + 4 'obtain the next last column for the following slice content dropping
 Next
 'clear the range starting from the 8th row:
 sh.Range(sh.cells(nrRows + 1, 1), sh.cells(lastRow, 4)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

But, since your question is not clear, at least for me, please also test the code version of vertically transposing:

```
Sub sliceArrayTransposeVert()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, slice, nrRows As Long
 Dim cols As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 nrRows = 7: cols = 4
 lastCol = sh.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 arr = sh.Range("A1:L7").Value
 For i = cols + 1 To lastCol Step cols
    slice = Application.Index(arr, Application.Evaluate("row(1:7)"), _
                   Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("row(" & i & ":" & i + cols - 1 & ")")))
    sh.cells(nrRows + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(slice), UBound(slice, 2)).Value = slice ': Stop
    nrRows = nrRows + 7
 Next
 sh.Range(sh.cells(1, cols + 1), sh.cells(7, lastCol)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tuấn Nguyễn: Couldn't you find some time to test the above code(s)? You did not answer my clarification questions, neither...

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in a module:

```
Public Sub SpreadBlocks(ByRef r_src As Range, ByVal n_rows As Long, ByRef r_dst As Range)

    Dim n_all_rows As Long, n_cols As Long
    n_all_rows = r_src.Worksheet.Range( _
        r_src, r_src.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    n_cols = r_src.Worksheet.Range( _
        r_src, r_src.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
        
    Dim n_blocks As Long, i As Long
    n_blocks = n_all_rows \ n_rows
    
    For i = 1 To n_blocks
        r_dst.Offset(0, (i - 1) * n_cols).Resize(n_rows, n_cols).Value2 = _
            r_src.Offset((i - 1) * n_rows, 0).Resize(n_rows, n_cols).Value2
    Next i

End Sub
```

To be called as follows:

```
Public Sub Test()

    SpreadBlocks Range("A2"), 7, Range("F2")
    '            |            |  |
    '            |            |  +-> Top left cell of destination
    '            |            +----> Number of rows for each block
    '            +-----------------> Top left cell of source

End Sub
```

[image: scr1]